# How to add item to ListView and to get the view?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

I try to create comments in ListView. I've comments' ArrayList linked to the ListView and I can print all the comments successfully. However, when I add another comment to my ArrayList and call notifyDataSetChanged and then try to find the view I get nullPointerException.

I guess what happens is the notifyDataSetChanged doesn't change the ListView immediately, but I couldn't find any solution to this problem.

```
private ArrayList<Comment> chatroomComments;
private CommentsListArrayAdapter adapter;
private ListView chatroomListView;
```

And this is how I try to get the view:

```
    chatroomComments.add(comment);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    View v = CommentsListArrayAdapter.positionToView
            .get(chatroomComments.size() - 1);
    adapter.setNewSelectedView(v);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how you try to get view. please put your code here

Comment: We cannot comment if you don"t tell what kind of adapter you use.

Comment: sorry ... edited now

Comment: What kind of adapter do you use?

Comment: Please post some more code